# Restrict HKSampleQuery results to those input from your own app

Tags: ios, nspredicate, healthkit, nssortdescriptor, hksamplequery

I wish to restrict results returned from a HealthKit HKSampleQuery to those that have been input through my own app. Is there a way to specify results only with my application bundle identifier, and thereby exclude any other data sources returned from other applications?

Is there a way to specify this with an `NSSortDescriptor` or `NSPredicate`, as I have tried below?

```
func querySteps() {
    // let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "bundleIdentifier", ascending: true, selector: "com.companyName.appName:")
    // let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "bundleIdentifier", "com.companyName.appName")

    let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: healthKitManager.stepsCount!,
        predicate: nil,
        limit: 100,
        sortDescriptors: nil)
        { [unowned self] (query, results, error) in
            if let results = results as? [HKQuantitySample] {
                self.steps = results
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                });

            }
    }

    healthStore?.executeQuery(sampleQuery)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple one line solution to the question above. Use `HKQuery` to create a predicate object that specifies the data's source:

```
let thePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjectsFromSource(HKSource.defaultSource())
```

And then swap out the `nil` predicate parameter value with `thePredicate`, in this case. Then, the results in your table view will show only your own app's `HKQuery` results.